# May I damage software by killing the process?

Tags: powershell, kill

Here is my situation: I have an authenticated proxy at work. I use proxyswitcher.net to change/remove the proxy accordingly to the network identification. Also, I made a powershell script that kills dropbox, changes de config file to the one with/without manual proxy configuration and I restart it.

From what I read, the risks of doing this is that some file may be corrupted while dropbox is writing it. I don´t think this is a problem as the script runs at the moment that the network is identified. Also, dropbox is very good at handling this type of errors.

But, is there a better way or other risks I´m not aware of it?

Comment: what happens if you don't kill dropbox during network switch? Could you simply stop the service and start it cleanly rather than kill?  Depends on the process, killing might leave corrupt writes...

Comment: Probably only dropbox would be able to provide a _definitive_ answer to this question, but I suspect that their file transfer algorithm is designed to be robust (i.e., tolerant of network or application interruptions).

Comment: I would agree that just leaving Dropbox running seems like a better idea. The software has to be designed to handle network drops.  What happens when you don't quit Dropbox when you update your network configuration?

Comment: I can´t overwrite de config.db file where this configuration is maintaned...

Answer (score -1):

I think, instead of using `kill`, you could try `Stop-Process`. Ex:
`Stop-Process -Name "dropbox"`

Comment: `kill` is an alias for `Stop-Process` so that would be exactly the same :)